# Map-reduce algorithm

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata

I can't understand a proper answer for these question. does anyone can help me for:
"Our formulation of matrix-vector multiplication assumed that
the matrix M was square. Generalize the algorithm to the case where M is an
r-by-c matrix for some number of rows r and columns c."

Answer (score 1):

I think what it's stating is that a square matrix-vector multiplication is

```
r-by-r . r-by-1 = M . V
```

Because a vector only has 1 column and where r is the size of the square (rows and columns) matrix. So to generalise this to a matrix M with r rows and c columns we have

```
r-by-c . c-by-1 = r-by-1 = M . V
```

Where V is a vector of length c, or in other words, a c-by-1 matrix